# Received MAC address of available WiFi networks are not true

Tags: c, wifi

I am trying to find MAC address of available "Wi_Fi"s in this area  but I receive wrong MAC address( at least I am sure about 1 access point MAC address here that I know is not the same with thing I receive) .

My code is:

```
       char MAC[64];

         int len=sizeof(MAC)/sizeof(int);
         int i;
            for(i=1;i<len;i++){
            MyScanResults = WFScanList(i);
           //unsigned long long testMac =MyScanResults.bssid[i];
           unsigned char* pTestMac = (unsigned char*)&MyScanResults.bssid[i];
           sprintf(MAC, "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
           (unsigned)pTestMac[6],
           (unsigned)pTestMac[5],
           (unsigned)pTestMac[4],
           (unsigned)pTestMac[3],
           (unsigned)pTestMac[2],
           (unsigned)pTestMac[1]
           );
```

and my expected answer is:

> bssid: 00:12:17:C6:F4:36

but each time I receive some addresses like this and some times this address change also:

> MAC:         73:6D:65:36:F4:C6

I have changed also order of numbers but nothing...
is there anyone to tell me where is my problem?
thanks
Regards

Comment: Uh, you know that C array indexing starts from 0, right? Because your code makes it look like you don't.

Comment: yes,but when I put 1 the shield get dissconnect and does't Scan any network

Comment: Well, the F4:36 is there, but one place out, (your dodgy indexing?), and reversed. The first bytes seem to have been overwritten?   Does the substring 'sme6' mean anything to you?

Comment: I didn't get what does "sme6" mean?

Comment: After each Reconnecting bits replace for example Now is: MAC:         65 36 F4 C6 17 12

Comment: OK, now you're one out 'cos dodgy indexing, like @unwind said at start.

Comment: @HOsseiNSA '73:6D:65:36' in ASCII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make a lot of sense.

You call `MyScanResults = WFScanList(i);` *before* even declaring `i`. Also, the looping and indexing from `1` is very suspect.

I also think the use of `i` is very strange throughout, the calculation of a pointer into `MyScanResults.bssid`, effectively slicing it, can't be right.

I think your loop should be something like:

```
for(i=0; i < WFNetworkFound; i++)
{
    const tWFNetwork myScanResults = WFScanList(i);
    sprintf(MAC, "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
       myScanResult.ssid[0],
       myScanResult.ssid[1],
       myScanResult.ssid[2],
       myScanResult.ssid[3],
       myScanResult.ssid[4],
       myScanResult.ssid[5]);
```

This assumes you've run the scan already so that the global variable `WFNetworkFound` has been updated. It also assumes that you're using openPicus, so that [this reference code](http://wiki.openpicus.com/index.php?title=WiFi_Scan) from which I picked up a thing or two is valid.

Comment: Yes sequence in my source code is true but here I made mistake.when It start from 0 the code does't show any Ouput.

Comment: thanks a lot.Just by replacing "myScanResult.ssid[..]" instead of            "(unsigned)pTestMac[]" I could get the correct result.